Unable to complete installing Ubuntu 24.04 LTS server
Hi I downloaded the ISO from official website and am trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 LTS server on VMware environment as guest OS and I faced the following error (excluded some lines) in the process of installation.
Ign:57 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-41-generic amd64 6.8.0-41.41
Err:57 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-41-generic amd64 6.8.0-41.41
Fetched 623 MB in 4min 47s (2172 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/1/linux/linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-41-generic_6.8.0-41.41_amd64.deb Connection failed
E: Some files failed to download
finish: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/builtin/cmd-curthooks/installing-kernel: FAIL: installing kernel
finish: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/builtin/cmd-curthooks: FAIL: curtin command curthooks
Traceback (most recent call last):
As error message says, there is no linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-41-generic_6.8.0-41.41_amd64.deb hosted on the link.
Is there anyway to complete the installation? Has anyone else experienced the same?

"Connection failed" sounds more like a network error - did you copy and paste the message - or transcribe it? I would expect it to be looking under pool/main/l/ (that's letter ell) not pool/main/1/ (digit one) where indeed it would find linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-41-generic_6.8.0-41.41_amd64.deb

hi, it turned out it was our proxy server unable to respond on time. First it tried to fetch the package from archive.ubuntu.com and then tried to fetch from security.ubuntu.com. The package exists on security.ubuntu.com but our proxy server couldn't fetch it somehow.
